# How to get the value of a specific column in a specific line in any time of processing in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I got a data file in the format like this:

```
# begin
16 1
15 2
14 3
13 4
12 5
11 6
```

Now I want to use gnuplot to draw a line through the points:

```
(1, (16/16))  (2, (16/15))  (3, (16/14)) ...  (6, (16/11))
```

As you see, the x axis is the range [1:6] and the Y axis corresponds the values obtained from the number in the first line at the first column(ie. 16 in this example) divided by the number in each line at the first column.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the value of the number at the first column in the first line (16), so that I could do something like

```
plot "datafile" using 2:(16/$1) with linespoints
```

I have done a lot of search about how to achieve that but with no luck. It seems that gnuplot doesn't provide some flexible ways to allow arbitrary data selection. Any ideas how to do that? Or maybe I just got stuck into a not so common problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `stats` command to extract a single numerical value from your data file. The row is selected with the `every` option, the column with the `using`:

```
col = 1
row = 0
stats 'datafile' every ::row::row using col nooutput
value = STATS_min

plot "datafile" using 2:(value/$1) w lp
```

Note, that column numbering starts at 1, and row numbering at 0 (comment lines are skipped and aren't counted).

Comment: This works fine in my latest version of gnuplot on my local machine. But I need to work on a remote machine whose gnuplot version is 4.2 with patchlevel 6. However the stats command is available from version 4.6. So do you know others ways to achieve the same goal? Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Or I would scp that data file to my local machine then generate the figure.

Comment: You can use e.g. awk to extract that value: `value = real(system('awk ''{if (NR == 2) print $1 }'' datafile'))`