# Read data in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with a matrix like :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Using gnuplot, I would like to extract the Variable in the 3th row on the 2th column, and store it in a variable called X for example. please how to do that using gnuplot.
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18587275/2604213 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/26925306/2604213

Answer (score 0):

You can do that within a `plot` command,

```
set table "/dev/null"
X=0
X_row=3
X_col=2
plot "file.dat" using (($0==X_row)?(X=column(X_col),X):0)
unset table
```

To save time the plot command can do something useful at the same time, like... plotting something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It's solved actually using this syntax :

```
plot u 0:($0==RowIndex?(VariableName=$ColumnIndex):$ColumnIndex)
#RowIndex starts with 0, ColumnIndex starts with 1
print VariableName
```

It's already explained quite well here :
[by @StackJack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211339/gnuplot-store-one-number-from-data-file-into-variable)

Comment: I would use `stats`. StackJack's is from a time when that function wasn't yet implemented.