# Display changing column value in Gnuplot animation

Tags: gnuplot

I am making a gnuplot animation of a satellite going around a planet. My task is to display it's XY trajectory and associated values of velocity and energy versus time. I know how to plot the path, but I've been having problems displaying velocity etc.

the code below does the following:
satellite track and time steps -- column 3:4;
satellite position -- column 3:4;
planet position --  column 6:7.

```
do for [n=0:int(STATS_records)] {

plot "sat.dat" u 3:4  every ::0::n w lp ls 2 t sprintf("steps=%i", n), \
     "sat.dat" u 3:4  every ::n::n w lp ls 4 notitle, \
     "sat.dat" u 6:7  every ::0::n w lp ls 3 notitle , \

    }
```

How do I display the associated velocity values for each sprintf ? The velocity values are in column 5. Thank you everyone in advance.

[image: satellite animation frame]

Comment: add example output

Comment: Animation frame is attached above see (imgur link). The data file contains 7 columns. Column 1 shows time steps, column2 is time, column3&4 is xy coordinates for coresponding time steps, column5 is corresponding velocity, column6&7 is planet coordinates (constant values).

Comment: Line numbers (rows) start with 0 and column numbers start with 1. You shouldn't have to round down the number of records, and the last value of the `for` range is inclusive. Maybe you want `[n=0:STATS_records-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to put everything in the "key" (legend), but another option is to use labels, which can be easily placed arbitrarily.  There are labels you can place one at a time (with `set label`) and `with labels` for plotting with actual labels.  Don't get them confused.

Your main issue seems to be how to pull out the velocity value from column 5.  My first instinct (which is quite hacky) is to use some external program, like `awk`:

```
v = system(sprintf("awk 'NR==%d{print $5}' '%s'", n+1, infile))
set label 1 sprintf("v=%.3f", v+0) at screen 0.2,0.9
```

This is also an example of a label (named `1`).  The `screen` keyword means screen-relative rather than graph-relative.  Putting this inside your `for` loop will reassign label `1` every iteration, so it overwrites the label from the previous iteration.  Not using this `1` will just plop another label on top of the last one, so it would get messy.

Using an external command line like this isn't very portable.  (I don't think it would work on Windows.)  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921329/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-specific-column-in-a-specific-line-in-any-time-of-proc) that shows how to pull a value from a specific row and column of a file.  The problem I had with using this is that `stats` implicitly filters according to whatever `xrange` is set.  When making animations like this, I've noticed that the camera can jump around too much from autoranging, so it's nice to have tight control over the plotting range.  Defining an `xrange` at the top of the file interfered with a subsequent `stats` command to read a velocity value.

You can, however, specify a range for `stats` (before the file name, such as `stats [*:*] infile`).  But I had issues using this in combination with a predefined `xrange` based for position.  I found that it did work if I specify the desired plotting range on the `plot` line instead of a `set xrange`.  Here is another (full script) version using only gnuplot:

```
set terminal pngcairo
infile = 'anim.dat'
stats infile using 3:4 name 'data' nooutput
set key font 'Courier'

do for [n=0:data_records-1] {
  set output sprintf('frame-%03d.png', n)
  stats [*:*] infile every ::n::n using 5 name 'velocity' nooutput

  plot [data_min_x:1.1*data_max_x][data_min_y:1.1*data_max_y] \
    infile u 3:4 every ::0::n w linespoints ls 2 t \
      sprintf("steps =%6d\nvelocity =%6.3f", n, velocity_min), \
    '' u 3:4 every ::n::n w points pt 7 ps 3 notitle
}
```

Notice that you could easily change this to a `set label` if you want.  Another option is to plot

```
'' u (x):(y):5 every ::n::n w labels
```

to place a label at graph position (*x*,*y*).

[image]

I don't have your data, but I made my own file with what I hope is a similar format to yours:

**anim.dat**

```
0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.11803398875 0.625
1 0.05 0.05 0.02375 1.09658560997 0.625
2 0.1 0.1 0.045 1.07703296143 0.625
3 0.15 0.15 0.06375 1.05948100502 0.625
4 0.2 0.2 0.08 1.04403065089 0.625
5 0.25 0.25 0.09375 1.0307764064 0.625
6 0.3 0.3 0.105 1.01980390272 0.625
7 0.35 0.35 0.11375 1.01118742081 0.625
8 0.4 0.4 0.12 1.00498756211 0.625
9 0.45 0.45 0.12375 1.00124921973 0.625
10 0.5 0.5 0.125 1.0 0.625
11 0.55 0.55 0.12375 1.00124921973 0.625
12 0.6 0.6 0.12 1.00498756211 0.625
13 0.65 0.65 0.11375 1.01118742081 0.625
14 0.7 0.7 0.105 1.01980390272 0.625
15 0.75 0.75 0.09375 1.0307764064 0.625
16 0.8 0.8 0.08 1.04403065089 0.625
17 0.85 0.85 0.06375 1.05948100502 0.625
18 0.9 0.9 0.045 1.07703296143 0.625
19 0.95 0.95 0.02375 1.09658560997 0.625
```

Comment: Thank you @e0k it worked!!! Implemented you code -- stats [*:*] etc, had one problem with a label that didn't overwrite from previous iteration, but I see that you had that covered with label 1. Once again thank you for your help !!!